# How to get face matching percentage instead of boolean value in face_recognition python library

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning

i am using [face_recognition](https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/) library for simple
face recognition which is simple and easy for any developer
[ *like me without machine learning or deep learning knowledge* ]

```py
import face_recognition
known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("knownimage.jpg")
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("unknown.jpg")

known_image_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

results = face_recognition.compare_faces([known_image_encoding], unknown_encoding)
```

here in

```
results = face_recognition.compare_faces([known_image_encoding], unknown_encoding)
```

i am getting `True or False` if face matched
is there anyway i can get value in percentage matched

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example [here](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/face_distance.py#L9) on the official github page that boils down to

```py
face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_encodings, image_to_test_encoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_encodings, image_to_test_encoding)

face_match_percentage = (1-face_distances)*100
for i, face_distance in enumerate(face_distances):
    print("The test image has a distance of {:.2} from known image #{}".format(face_distance, i))

    print("- comparing with a tolerance of 0.6? {}".format(face_distance < 0.6))
    
    print (numpy.round(face_match_percentage,4)) #upto 4 decimal places
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this explanation may solve the question, including a sample code of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. I suggest you to edit your answer to add some code example, Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks!